# an error related to the import of a project file in the context of .NET development with Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk

Tags: .net, runtime-error

## Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error       Project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk\7.0.101\Sdk\AutoImport.props" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props" at (14,3), due to the file being invalid.  back    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk\7.0.101\Sdk\AutoImport.props   14

can you any one solve that issue